# Exchange 2010 - Archiving emails and restricting user access

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I want to implement a retention policy which looks like this:

After 1 year move messages 1 year or older to personal archive - all users can access this and it is already setup.

**After 3 years - move messages 3 years or older to another database which can only be accessed for HR/Legal purposes.**

Delete all messages 5 years or older.

Is there any way to remove user access to the messages moved into the legal/HR database?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this a couple of ways.

1. Set a 3 year retention on the archive mailboxes, but have backups on tape or virtual tapes for 5 years. You can restore the backups to PST when a case calls for them. (this was the old way we did it)
2. Use an "in place hold" instead of a retention policy. I'm not sure how to do this in Exchange 2010, (we skipped from 7 to 13), but we currently setup in place holds that only legal can see, but the user can't.

This article may help.
http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/compliance-policies-archiving/exchange-2010-litigation-hold-part1.html